# amCharts: Pie chart animation not working

Tags: pie-chart, amcharts

I am using more than one pie chart from `amCharts` on a single page, when the page is loading the animation is not working, and I want it to work. Below is my code which is used to render chart.

```
var Piechart132 = AmCharts.makeChart('div132', {
    labelsEnabled: false,
    autoMargins: false,
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    pullOutRadius: 0,
    type: 'pie',
    theme: 'dark',
    dataProvider: [
        { country: 'Banking', litres: 300000000 },
        { country: 'Carpenter', litres: 349500000000 },
        { country: 'Doctor', litres: 433650000000 },
        { country: 'Gas', litres: 108326000000 },
        { country: 'Mechanic', litres: 366450000000 }
    ],
    outlineThickness: 1,
    outlineAlpha: 1,
    legend: { enabled: true, valueText : '' },
    outlineColor: undefined,
    titles: [{ text: 'Industry wise Exposure' }],
    valueField: 'litres',
    titleField: 'country',
    balloon: { fixedPosition: true }
});
```

One more than I want to mention that same code when I execute on Fiddle, it is working fine, it might be possible that there is any other conflict but I can't find it anyway. I've even tried to insert `startDuration and set its value to`20` so that at least I can see what the problem is but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The pie charts definitely do animate when multiple charts are on the same page, however they might all bog down the browser if they're all initialized at once, leading to a choppy experience where the animation runs too quickly or are so choppy that they appear to not work. You may want to consider a lazy-loading technique in which you use each chart's `init` event  to initialize the next chart after a delay, or the lazy load techniques described in the AmCharts knowledge base links below:

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/lazy-loading-120-charts-page/

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/make-the-charts-lazy-initialize-only-when-they-scroll-into-view/

Comment: This doesn't address the issue at all. He's asking how to make a cheeseburger and you give him instructions on how to cook fries. I'm running into the exact same issue, even with just one chart on the page, and only with a pie chart type.

Comment: Can you provide a link that reproduces this? How much data do you have? What else is going on your page? Browser version? Given the limited information both he and you provided, it's hard to provide any other suggestions. I'd be happy to help if you gave me more to work with. The so-called fry making instructions typically work for our users that are having issues with multiple charts at once unless there's something else going on and slowness with one chart is pretty uncommon. Feel free to add to the thread or reach out to amcharts support and we'd be happy to dive into this with you.

Comment: My problem was that something with a pie chart doesn't work in a react component (though series works fine). I was able to get around it with a simple bit to re-force the animation: `if(props.options.type === 'pie') {
            this.refs.chart.style.visibility = "hidden";
            setTimeout(()=>{
                this.refs.chart.style.visibility = "visible";
                this.chart.animateAgain();
            },500);
        }`

Comment: Gotcha. This problem is different than the one posted by the user, though. Are you using our [react component](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-react/) or a home-spun one? If it's the former, a bug report would be appreciated. We try our best to make everything functional with modern frameworks, but the current version of our library is very long in the tooth. For what it's worth, our next major version, v4, is being built to support modern frameworks out of the box, though v4 will not be API compatible with v3. If you have any other issues, feel free to reach out to us.